# Wire gauges thickness/connector type for speaker level wire

Tags: connector, wire

So I'm wondering what wire thickness is required for a homemade speaker level wire (200w amp head output over maybe 10cm)? And what connector type would be recommended for the wire type (I would like to connect 2 5cm wires together).
[image]

Comment: Are you saying it is really only 10 cm (100 mm) from your amp to your speaker?

Comment: For this part of the connection is 10cm (it is going through a 10cm wall and I want to make it myself). Both sides of the wall will be connecting via https://www.thomann.de/se/neutrik_nj_3fp6cb.htm then normal speaker level line cables will carry the cable from the wall to/from amp and speaker.

Comment: You're asking what connectors to use but you haven't shown information about what you want to connect to.  Are they screw down posts or squeezy ones?  What are you plugging in to?  Also you've said level wire, do you mean a signal wire or are you actually talking about the pair of wires that drive the speaker?

Comment: @KH Oh sorry! Two wires together. Speaker level wire, which will carry a high load (not to active spreakers (not line level in other words)). Think a 200w guitar amp head and speaker cabinets.

Comment: @KH I updated with a picture, I hope this resolves any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to make your cable resistance ≤ 1/10 of your speaker resistance which will most likely be 4 Ω or 8 Ω.

There are plenty of resistance calculators on line such as [Omni Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance) which will do the calculations for you. A quick check for a 10 m loop (5 m out and back) with a 0.4 Ω target shows that 0.5 mm<sup>2</sup> cable would do the job.

Comment: Oh wow, I would thought a 200w amp 10m loop run to stacked speakers would of required quite a thick wire! Speaker wires are after all quite stiff in nature.

Comment: @KarlMorrison   16 or 18g "Zip cord" is more than ideal and very economical.  The same stuff used for lamp cords.  Don't fall for the 'oxygen free', 'shielded', 'helical wound'  and other BS.  As Transistor says (I paraphrase) you care about resistance.  The above 1/10 is a good start... Personally I'd go even further.  Besides the loss of power (which isn't much), having excess resistance will also negatively affect the amps damping characteristic... It can make the bass frequencies "floppy".   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-3rgu9Um7s

Comment: Thanks for that info man! Any idea on pin connectors?

Comment: What on connectors? You said you're using Neutrik jack sockets.

Comment: @Transistor The wire inside the wall is cut in the middle. I do not want to solder them together as I would like to disconnect them from each other so I need a connector for them.

Comment: @Karl, this is getting a bit silly now. Use any connector that the wires will fit into. Better still is to use the wires to pull new wires through and connect them to the Neutrik connectors.

Comment: @Transistor Actually I found the answer on a different website. No, you can't just use "any connector", apparently connectors have Amp ratings. I don't know about you, but I take electrical safety and sound quality very serious.

Comment: @Karl, If you twist the wires together and they fit inside a screw terminal then that's all you need. Very little current will flow through the connector as there is wire to wire interface. I'm an electrical engineer for 40+ years. :^)